# encoding a ruby 1.8.7 string

Tags: ruby, encoding, hex

I am trying to implement the following C++ code in Ruby:

```
sprintf (tmp, "|%02x", Payload[i] & 0xFF);
```

Basically, all bytes in the payload data whose value is not a code of letters or numbers in the US-ASCII code table, are encoded as three bytes:

```
| X1 X2
```

where '|' is a byte with the value of code of character '|' in the US-ASCII code table (0x7C), 'X1' is a first hexadecimal digit of the code of the byte, and 'X2' is a second hexadecimal digit of the code of the byte.

Up until now, I have coded this:

```
payload.each_char do |char|
  if char.match(/^[[:alnum:]]$/) 
    encoded_string << char && next 
  end
  encoded_string << sprintf("|%02x", char.hex);  
end
```

Problem is, this does not work correctly for special symbols like '*' and others.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: What happens with symbols like `*`?

Comment: Ruby 1.8 does not support encodings, and therefore you cannot use `char.hex`, as the character type can only store US-ASCII characters.

Comment: Ok, I know that Ruby 1.8 does not support encodings. How then to implement the same behavior as the C++ code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have 1.8.7 to test with but this worked in 1.9.3, and all the methods used should be in 1.8.7:

```
payload.each_byte do |byte|
  if byte.chr.match(/^[[:alnum:]]$/) 
    encoded_string << byte.chr && next 
  end
  encoded_string << sprintf("|%02x", byte);  
end
```

Result with `"hello world***"`:

```
hello|20world|2a|2a|2a
```

Comment: THat's funny, I implemented the _SAME_ code, it worked, but while I find the time to paste it here (talking to a colleague), you pasted it. Awesome!